# Grok returns array instead of single string

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I'm new to grok and I have run into this issue that I just don't know how to solve.

Below is my grok match:

```
grok {
      match => { "source" => "/var/log/nginx/sites/\b\w+\b/\b\w+\b/\b\w+\b/%{DATA:uuid}/" }
    }

    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}"
        "token" => "%{[fields][token]}"
        "logzio_codec" => "%{[fields][logzio_codec]}"
        "uuid" => "%{uuid}"
        "type" => "%{[fields][type]}"
        "category" => "%{[fields][category]}"
      }
    }
```

for some reason, the uuid is matched and resulted in array of 2 uuid (duplicated values). Instead of `uuid_string` I get [`uuid_string`, `uuid_string`]

I tried on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and got what I expected so I wonder what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So once again I misunderstand how grok works. It seems like once the match is done, all the fields are already added to the output. The additional add_field uuid in the mutate thus causes the field to be added twice and logstash then thinks it's an array.